# Make FindInstance accept only parametrized solutions

Tags: equation-solving, boolean-computation

I have for example the following conditions:

```
condition={Subscript[K, 1] < 
  1 || (Subscript[K, 1] >= 
    1 && (Subscript[K, 2] < 1 - E^(-2 v1 + v2) || 
     Subscript[K, 2] > -E^(-2 v1 + v2) + Subscript[K, 1]))}
```

Where I consider `Subscript[K, 1]` and `Subscript[K, 2]` as unknowns and v1 and v2 as parameters. I would like to fine instances of `Subscript[K, 1]` and `Subscript[K, 2]` that satisfy the above condition, and would like such istances to depend on v1 and v2. For example:

```
{Subscript[K, 1],Subscript[K, 2]}={1,-3-Exp[-2 v1 + v2]}
```

In other words I would like to find instances that discard cases that do not include the parameters, v1 and v2. 
I've tried using FindInstance[] as follows:

```
FindInstance[condition, Array[Subscript[K, #] &, 2]]
```

Yet it goes for solutions of the first case, that do not include the parameters. How may obtain the desired solutions for this problem? I'm looking for a generic solution to the problem as I wish to apply this to a generic condition depending on parameters.